# Combining two PDF's in itext

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have two ByteArrayOutputStreams which contain PDF files. 
I used java concatinate operation and it failed.
I want to add the second pdf after the first one.

Is there any Itext functions to merge two Pdfs using streams?

Comment: You can retrieve the underlying `byte []`s from your `ByteArrayOutputStreams`, open `PdfReaders` with them, and concatenate them using`PdfCopy`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14003362/1862502

Answer (score 0):

Found it atlast..This one worked for me

```
Document document = new Document();
        //Rectangle pageSize = new  Rectangle(792, 612);
        Rectangle pageSize = PageSize._11X17;
        document.setPageSize(pageSize);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
        document.open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

        for (InputStream in : list) {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(in);
            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                document.newPage();
                //import the page from source pdf
                PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
                //add the page to the destination pdf
                cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        outputStream.flush();
        document.close();
        outputStream.close();
```

Comment: Using an actual `PdfWriter` instance here generally is less than optimal. Most likely a `PdfCopy` or `PdfSmartCopy` instance is better suited to your needs.